# How to kill, Store, and open a process in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, process

I'm getting the list of running process, kill a specific process and then open it again  when the Form close.

the problem is that to open again the process when the form close i'm searching the program into the specific path

```
 If File.Exists("path") Then
        Dim t As Process = Process.Start("path")
    Else
        Return
    End If
```

Is it possible store the process somewhere before killing it and then call it again once the form is closing?
I'm asking this question because if someone choose to install a program into another path for, this code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Process.MainModule.FileName` to get the fully qualified path before you kill the process. You can then store this string until you need to start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no registry entry for the installation path, you can search for the file and reference the path:

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
     My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
     Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "path")

     Listbox1.Items.Add(foundFile.Substring(0, foundFile.LastIndexOf("\"))) 
Next
```

Source:
[How to: Find Files with a Specific Pattern in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zwyt2y8.aspx)